# Using shQuote with R on Windows

Tags: windows, r

I am testing out the bio3d package in R (Windows) and encountered a rather general problem:

The "seqaln" function in bio3d tries to issue the following system command:

```
#cmd = "muscle -in C:\\Users\\derek\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpUSXJCb\\file756f52c9 -out c:/pdb/temp.fas  -seqtype protein"
system(shQuote(cmd))
```

As far as I can tell, nothing happened. However, once I removed the "shQuote", the function - seqaln - worked as expected. All shQuote does is added a pair of "" around the command:

```
"\"C:/_utils/muscle.exe -in C:\\Users\\kfoo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpUSXJCb\\file756f52c9 -out c:/pdb/temp.fas  -seqtype protein\""
```

Is there something wrong with using shQuote?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying `shQuote()` to a character string that contains both a command and it's arguments. None of the examples in `shQuote()` does that, and neither should you!

The following doesn't work, for the same reason that `\"echo HelloWorld\"` fails when typed directly at Windows' `cmd` command line:

```
system(shQuote("echo HelloWorld"))
```

Instead, you should do the following:

```
system("echo HelloWorld")
# HelloWorld
```

Or, if both your command and its argument may contain spaces, you can use `shQuote()` like this:

```
system(paste(shQuote("echo"), shQuote("HelloWorld")))
# HelloWorld
```

Comment: best alternative: `system2('command', shQuote(c('Hello World', 'second arg')))`